# I need a way to manipulate the last character in a JTextArea (by deleting it)

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I have a JTextArea that I can fill with text using JButtons. I want a JButton that I can use a backspace without using the Robot class or the backspace key, but just by clicking the button on the screen with my mouse. How do I manipulate the text using `public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {` of a JTextArea using this button, by using a self-created backspace key? Let me know if you have any questions or are confused on what I'm asking.

Comment: Please show your code for an already programmed `JButton` or two that populate your `JTextArea`.

Comment: @PM77-1 I don't actually have access to the code as of now, but I will put the code up in a few hours, when I have access to the code.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [`Document`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/Document.html).

Every text component in Swing has a `Document` model which controls the state of the text (and where applicable, the attributes and structure).

You can use the `JTextArea`'s `Document` to remove characters directly.

Something like...

```
Document doc = textArea.getDocument();
doc.remove(doc.getLength() - 2, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can substring method from string

```
String text = textArea.getText();
textArea.setText(text.subString(0, text.length() - 1);
```

Comment: While true, that's a lot of new `String` objects you're creating

Answer (score 0):

Remove last line from `JtextArea`

```
JtextArea.setText(JtextArea.getText().substring(0,JtextArea.getText().lastIndexOf("\n")));
```